# When can double ampersand && be shortend to a single &

Tags: rust

In pattern matching, one can append `&[&] [mut]` to an identifier like `&e` in `v.iter().filter(|&e| ...)`. This is called [*reference patterns*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns).

When playing with this pattern, I found an inconsistent behavior:

- For a doubly borrowed value, `&&e` works but `&e` also works.
- When mutable, however, `&&mut e` works whilst `&mut e` doesn't work.

Why?

```rust
fn main() {

    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    v.iter()
        .filter(|e| *e * 2 >= 8)
        .for_each(|e| println!("{}", e)); //=> 4 5

    v.iter()
        .filter(|e| **e * 2 >= 8)
        .for_each(|e| println!("{}", e));

    v.iter()
        .filter(|&e| e * 2 >= 8)
        .for_each(|e| println!("{}", e));

    v.iter()
        .filter(|&&e| e * 2 >= 8)
        .for_each(|e| println!("{}", e));

    //NG
    // v.iter_mut()
    //     .filter(|&mut e| e * 2 >= 8)
    //     .for_each(|e| println!("{}", e));

    v.iter_mut()
        .filter(|&&mut e| e * 2 >= 8)
        .for_each(|e| println!("{}", e));

}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41b0e62b79cc936a48c7207f5fea655a)

Answer (score 5):

**From high level perspective:**

`&mut T` is a mutable reference of type `T` and `&&mut T` is a immutable reference of `&mut T`.

**From compiler perspective:** ([ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns))

> The grammar production for reference patterns has to match the token
> `&&` to match a reference to a reference because it is a token by
> itself, not two `&` tokens.
>
> Adding the mut keyword dereferences a mutable reference

Basically  `&&` points the immutable reference to a immutable reference if there is a `mut`, it dereferences to a mutable reference *(immutable ref to mutable ref, i.e. as mentioned above)*.

---

> - When mutable, however, &&mut e works whilst &mut e doesn't work.

`&mut e` doesn't work because [method filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) from `std::iter` expects you to define a closure with immutable referenced parameter:

```rust
fn filter<P>(self, predicate: P) -> Filter<Self, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

`&&mut T` pattern works because `Self::Item` is a `&mut T` since you are using `iter_mut()`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Rust Complier says :** you can borrow multiple immutable references, but you
> cannot borrow multiple mutable references in a defined scope.

---

```
let e = 23;
```

here we can borrow multiple immutable references of `&e` or reference of reference `&&e` and our code will not break, because compiler knows all the references are immutable, hence no one can change the value.

but, lets say we borrow a mutable reference of a reference `&&mut e` , here the problem is we have two mutable references of same object(I: `&mut e`, II: `&&mut e`) anyone can change the value of `e`, and as per rule we are not allowed to have two mutable references of same object in scope.

*P.S. Please correct me if i'm wrong.*